# Ifelse statement inside deSolve not working

Tags: r, simulation, modeling, differential-equations, systemdynamics

I want to create a Dynamic model of butterfly ecology using deSolve. the simulation runs over several simulation years and some events are triggered by the day of the year (so I added one state variable of `days`  ). in order to trigger those events I want to use an `ifelse` statement and it works fine, until I try to put in the `ifelse` statement an operation involving another state variable: `D.egg.sus=(ifelse(days<270,(400 * adult.sus),0))`.
When I do so, the simulation runs, but it seems to ignore the `ifelse` statement. 
 can anyone help me please?  here is my full code:

```
days        = 1
egg.sus     = 0
larvae.sus  = 0 
pupae.sus   = 0 
adult.sus   = 1000

state = c(days = days, egg.sus=egg.sus, larvae.sus=larvae.sus,      
pupae.sus=pupae.sus, adult.sus=adult.sus)
model = function(t, state, parameters)
{ 
    with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), 
         {
    D.Days = 1
    D.egg.sus     =
        ( ifelse(days<270, (400*adult.sus) ,0))  ## This is the line causing trouble
        (- egg.sus/5) 
        (-  egg.sus * rbeta(1, 6.038892/5,1.4612593)*.95)                                                                                     
    D.larvae.sus  =
        (+ egg.sus/5) 
        (- larvae.sus * rbeta(1, 0.248531/14,0.2094379)*0.95)
        (- larvae.sus/14)                                                              
    D.pupae.sus   =  
        (+ larvae.sus/14)
        (- pupae.sus * rbeta(1, 0.022011/15, 1.43503))
        (- pupae.sus/15) 
    D.adult.sus   = 
        (+ pupae.sus/15) 
        (- adult.sus/30) 

    list(c( D.Days, D.egg.sus, D.larvae.sus,D.pupae.sus, D.adult.sus))
}
)}

events <- data.frame(var    = c('days'),
                 time   = seq(364,73000,by=365) ,
                 value  = 0,
                 method = "rep")

require(deSolve)

times = seq(1,900, by = 1) 
out = ode(y=state, times = times, func = model, parms = parameters,  events = list(data=events))

dev.cur()
plot(out, col = 2)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your model parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about five years ago, but at the time of writing `ifelse` works just fine with `deSolve`. Your issue seems to be that the returned value of your condition did not return as you wanted. Instead you might want to use a flag variable or save the return from your `ifelse` to a variable that you can then use in your model.

Here is a small example demonstrating how you can use a flag in your model parameters

```r
library(deSolve)

# Our model function, first-order
# One parameter is a flag that is used by the ifelse to set Ka to zero if TRUE.

onecomp <- function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    
    Ka = ifelse(flag == TRUE, 0, Ka) # Use ifelse to check for negative values
    
    dX <- - X*Ka
    dY <- X*Ka - Y*Ke
    list(c(dX, dY))
  })
}

times <- seq(0, 24, by = 0.01)
parameters <- c(Ka = 0.8 , Ke = 0.2, flag = FALSE)
state <- c(X = 100 , Y = 0)

# Test for TRUE
out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = onecomp, parms = parameters)
plot(out)
```

[image]

```r
# Test for FALSE, where we expect no transfer.
parameters <- c(Ka = 0.8 , Ke = 0.2, flag = TRUE)
out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = onecomp, parms = parameters)
plot(out)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The model in the question has several issues:

1. You can use the simulation time directly instead of a state variable `days`, because simulation time in the function is given as `t`. Then just use the modulo operator `%%` and you don't need events anymore.
2. the parameters are all hard-coded, so use `parms=NULL`in the ode function.
3. line breaks are wrong. **R** continues lines if (and only if) they are not yet syntactically complete. Therefore, remove obsolete parentheses and, for example, put the `-` operator
   at the end of the line.
4. Use of a random number e.g. `rgamma` within an ODE function is a very bad idea, especially for solvers with automatic time steps. ODEs are deterministic by definition. One may consider a fixed time-step solver instead, e.g. `method="euler"`with a **very small** time step or (much better) to provide the random values as an external input (forcing).
5. If you use an external input, you can avoid the `ifelse` anyway.

Comment: ... and looking once again, I am not sure if this is really an ODE. Can it be possible that you have a difference equation in mind?